# How to solve the equation $x^2 - 6x + 25 = 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

There is one thing that I don't understand.

How is it possible that $-6x$ can be into "$9$".

Can you describe it to me by calculation?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: $x_{1,2}=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$. Your $a,b,c$ are $+1,-6,+25$ respectively.

Comment: $x^2-6x+25=(x-3)^2+16$

Comment: Does anyone else find the skip from step 1 to step 2 rather hilarious in light of delineating how to get from step 2 to step 3? Kind of preposterous.

Comment: The OP's point, a way of looking at it, seems like this:

$$ x = \pm \sqrt{6 \ x - 25}  \tag{1}$$

substitute  9 in place of $6 x $

$$ x = \pm \sqrt {9 - 25}  \tag{2}$$

What relation of coefficients of a quadratic equation should hold for such plug-ins, he perhaps wants to know. If so its easy to find.

Comment: The process is known as completing the square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, in general roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are calculated as follows $$x=\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$

Now, we have $$x^2-6x+25=0$$ Using square formula, we get $$x=\frac{-(-6)\pm\sqrt{(-6)^2-4(1)(25)}}{2(1)}$$
 $$=\frac{6\pm\sqrt{-64}}{2}$$ $$=\frac{6\pm8i}{2}=3\pm4i$$

Hence, the roots are complex

Comment: http://www.freemathhelp.com/quadratic-formula.html

Comment: http://www.regentsprep.org/regents/math/algtrig/ate3/quadformula.htm

Answer (score 4):

Since $6$ is even they use a modified version of the quadratic formula:
$$ax^2 + 2b'x +c=0$$
$$\Delta ' = b'^2 - a*c$$
$$x=\frac {-b' \pm \sqrt{\Delta'}}{a}$$

The $2$ is simplified from the original formula.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $x^2-6x+25=(x-3)^2+16$. Here $16=25-9$

This is a general phenomenon. $x^2-2mx+n=(x-m)^2+n-m^2$. The $9$ comes from the fact that in your case $2m=6$ and $m^2=9$.

The point is that $(x-3)^2=x^2-6x+9$